# using `git commit —no-verify` for pre-commit azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I see that I can use pre-commit with pipelines, is there a way to set up the yaml file for azure pipeline to use `git commit --no-verify` when if fails for specific cases? or is there a way to troubleshoot the pipeline when the issue occurs?

this is what I have for the yaml file

```
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
  variables:
    PRE_COMMIT_HOME: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/pre-commit-cache

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: ${{ parameters.python }}
  - script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PY]$(python -VV)"
    displayName: set version variables
  - task: CacheBeta@0
    inputs:
      key: pre-commit | .pre-commit-config.yaml | "$(PY)" 
      path: $(PRE_COMMIT_HOME)

  - script: python -m pip install --upgrade pre-commit
    displayName: install pre-commit
  - script: pre-commit run --all-files --show-diff-on-failure
    displayName: run pre-commit
```

Comment: is there something stopping you from `|| true` or `|| git commit`? what behaviour are you trying to get out of this?

Comment: @AnthonySottile I want the pre commit hooks to run in the pipeline but in instances where the static analysis fails because of hook that's flagging an error for reasons that are acceptable, I would like to be able to override in the pipeline. I know locally I can run `git commit --no-verify`, there something similar I can do within the pipeline?

Comment: yeah you'd use `|| true`, or `SKIP` environment variable -- but `--no-verify` just skips the whole thing so you'd just not run it at all right?

Comment: @AnthonySottile oh I see, yes, and that's not what I want, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation [here](https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks):

> Not all hooks are perfect so sometimes you may need to skip execution
> of one or more hooks. pre-commit solves this by querying a `SKIP`
> environment variable. The `SKIP` environment variable is a comma
> separated list of hook ids. This allows you to skip a single hook
> instead of `--no-verifying` the entire commit.
>
> `$ SKIP=flake8 git commit -m "foo"`

Comment: Is my reply helpful? How's your issue going?